# Ask Community to Pick Answer

Tags: support

I've asked a question that has received multiple answers, but I don't know enough about the concepts mentioned in some answers to make an informed decision as to which is the best. In addition, I do not know if any, all, or none of the answers are correct. Is there a way to ask the Community or moderators to select an answer?

Comment: You can discuss the question in chat if you want. You can also leave it open and wait for time to pick the best answer. You might learn new things and then understand more and pick then - it is entirely up to you what you do - don't feel pressured to pick an answer as "the" correct one.

Comment: Consider that by community voting, the community is effectively "choosing" an answer. But you don't have to feel pressured to select one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't *have* to pick an answer, though if there are more than one good answers its always good to pick one.

You can ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table), however, and someone should turn up. Or just wait a bit and let the votes help you decide :)

Comment: +1 for voting. :-)